# Difference of Two Columns Greater Than Threshold Ignoring Errors In Excel

Tags: excel, sum, countif

I have the following formula in excel that i want to take the difference between columns V and S and count the number of rows that exceeds some threshold, say 0. It works if all the columns have numbers but if there are errors i receive #VALUE back. How would i change this formula ignore those rows? I've tried using ISNA and ISERROR but have not been able to get them to work.

`=SUMPRODUCT(--(V12:V20-S12:S20>U2))`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use this array formula:

```
=SUM(IFERROR(--(V12:V20-S12:S20>U2),0))
```

Being an array formula it must be confirmed with Ctrl-Shift-Enter instead of enter when exiting edit mode.

[image]

Comment: does not appear to be working. Returns zero with the following data
96.45 96.1
105.5 105.58
108.375 108.176
103.375 103.25
99.5         99.964
99.75 99.255
98.81 98.137
98.24 97.518
60.25 59.914

the thresold is .125 so the 5th row should be counted?

Comment: Did you use Ctrl-Shift-Enter instead of Enter when exiting edit mode?  Did Excel put `{}` around the formula?

Comment: Remember that if this worked to mark as correct by clicking the check mark by the answer.